# How can I trigger a get from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry about the relatively vague title, I can't think of anything better.

Anyway, so I have a page that shows a camera feed and I want to control pan/tilt. I've a python cgi that controls the actual nuts and bolts of that and spits out the html, the image being updated by javascript, and is looking for ?action=(left|right|up|down). I'm trapping key presses for that bit, but I can't figure out how to trigger a GET to the cgi without reloading the whole page. Is there any way I can do this or will I just have to reload the page?

Thanks

Comment: this is called doing ajax. try googling for that.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: This business of making requests without reloading the page is called AJAX (asynchronous JavaScript and XML).  Lot's of libraries have tools to get you started with this. SO specifically loves jQuery's version, refer to j08691's link.

Comment: And what is with SO's addiction to jQuery? ;)  Kidding, it's much easier to use jQuery most of the time for actual client applications.  When developing for personal projects though, I tend not to muck around with libraries that much.

Answer (score 3):

use [ajax get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)..

try this

```
 $.get('path/to/cgi',{data:"test"},function(data){
    alert("done");
 })
```

the first option is url..the path to where you need to send your datas to. 
the second parameter (optional) is the data object you need to send to your cgi,
the third  (optional) is the success callback function which is called when you get the response from the cgi successfully

you can get the data in you cgi by GET method